# CWA migration 1.5.04 to CWA 2011

Tags: 2011, content-delivery, upgrade

Today we are using CWA 1.5.04 (with TDF 1.4.03). We've planned to move to CWA 2011. After having updated jar files according to the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_CWA_10&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=UpgradingCWA.xml&docid=task_C1FECE85AD5E4F0BB3957C4516D7E2AC&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDoctask_C1FECE85AD5E4F0BB3957C4516D7E2AC), we are facing some compilation errors, especially with the jar cd_tdf.jar .

1 - Some packages have been renamed or moved. Ex: com.tridion.profserv.generic --> com.tridion.tdf.generic

--> Not a big deal (simple refactor) but troublesome.

2 - Some methods have disapeared, especially in the class Utils.

--> With the previous version, in *com.tridion.profserv.generic.utils.Utils*, we were using the method getTridionDate(). But with the new version, *com.tridion.tdf.generic.utils.Utils*, this method (and some others) have been removed.

Is there another way to obtain the same result ie a Date object from a String formated by Tridion ? Of course we could re-implement it by ourself but we would like to avoid to patch this kind of treatment. This is linked to the way Tridion is storing data in the Broker DB.

Thank you

Comment: One of the biggest changes with this release is indeed the fact that it moved from being a Professional Services add-on to an officially supported, "part-of-the-Tridion-Core" functionality. I would suggest also opening a support ticket with these questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TDF part of CWA 2011 has specifically changed most of the namespaces so you can still use the old TFD with the new CWA. If you wish to use some utility methods that you were using from old TDF, you're free to keep on using them. TDF was not fully included in CWA 2011. Only the pieces used specifically by CWA were brought to this version. Keep in mind that the Metadata Processor (for example) is not in this (minimal) version of TDF.

As a conclusion, if you're using utility methods from TDF, keep on using them together with the latest version of TDF.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok thank for the explanation. It's surprising but it's clear :D.